# Average of products of numbers taken from a finite field

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, modular-arithmetic

There is this domain I'm working in, where you pick $r$ random integers between $0$ and $p-1$, inclusive.  All calculations are done mod $p$.   Then, you get all multiples of each number $x$ from $-a \cdot x$ to $a \cdot x$.  Finally, you find all unique numbers of the form $c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + \dots + c_r x_r$, where $c_k$ ranges from $-a$ to $a$.

Between all of the numbers there are $(2a+1)^r$ combinations, but not all of them are unique.  I'm trying to model this distribution.  For instance, I really need to know the average number of unique combinations, if I pick $r$ numbers and use the $2a+1$ powers for each of the $r$ numbers.

I really don't know how to start...  I think that I might be able to use conditional probabilities.  I would really appreciate some help.

**EDIT 5/8/2020**

Here I will show what happens for $p=7$, $r=2$ and $a=1$...

Here is a table with all of the different inputs to the problem:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
x & -1 x & 0 x & 1 x \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 6 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 5 & 0 & 2 \\
3 & 4 & 0 & 3 \\
4 & 3 & 0 & 4 \\
5 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\
6 & 1 & 0 & 6
\end{array}$$

You can see the different values of $-x$, $0x$, and $1x$ in the table for different $x$ values.  Since $r=2$, we will add all possible values from $r=2$ of the rows in the table.  Here is a second table that lists how many combinations are possible between a given row and column:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 5 \\
2 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 7 \\
3 & 3 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 7 \\
4 & 3 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 7 \\
5 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 7 \\
6 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 5 \\
\end{array}$$

For example, if $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = 5$, row $2$ and column $5$ in the table says that there are 5 combinations.  This comes from all 5 different sums from adding all combinations of the list

$$\{-1(2), 0(2), 1(2)\} \equiv \{5, 0, 2\}$$

with all combinations of the list

$$\{-1(5), 0(5), 1(5)\} \equiv \{2, 0, 5\}$$

i.e. We can get the numbers $\{0+0, 0+2, 5+5, 2+2, 5+0\} \equiv \{0,2,3,4,5\}$.

The final result in this example is that the average over all possible combinations is that the average is

$$\frac{265}{7 \cdot 7} = \frac{265}{49} \approx 5.40816$$

I hope this helps with understanding the problem, and thank you for your interest!

Comment: What's a unique number?

Comment: @ancientmathematician It was a plus sign.  Also, I mean every number that is not equivalent modulo $p$.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @ancientmathematician  A unique number has each $c$ value ranging from $-a$ to $a$.

Comment: To be clear: you want to know the distribution of the cardinality of the set $\{\vec{c}\cdot\vec{x}: \vec{c}\in\langle[-a\ldots a]^r\rangle\}$, 'with respect to' the vector $\vec{x}\in F_p^r$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm not totally sure I understand...  I basically pick a vector $X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_r \}$.  Then, I create a superset, call it $S$, that includes any element of the form $c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2+\dots+c_r x_r$.  Here $c_k$ ranges from $-a$ to $a$.  I'm trying to eliminate duplicate numbers, when they occur, so I'm left with the average amount of distinct integers that have the desired format.  I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think you are right, but  s/he does say in the question "pick $r$ random integers ...$", so it ought to be clarified whether this means with or without replacement. I think the question might attract answers if it were edited in the way you are suggesting.

Comment: @Mathemagician I think an example would help here. Let's take $r=2$, $p=5$, say, and $a=1$. Then what specifically would the answer be in this sample case?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I edited the question.  I tried to give a thorough walk-through of the problem.  I hope that this helps.  The question is more complicated than I initially thought it would be.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: I do mean that the integers are picked _with replacement_.  Thanks for helping clarify that!

Comment: Is this what you mean?: (i) Fix a prime $p$, and natural numbers $r,a$. (ii) For each $x=(x_1,\dots,x_r)\in\mathbb{F_p}^r$ define $N_{a,r}(x)=|\{c_1 x_1+\dots+c_r x_r| -(2a+1)\leqslant c_i \leqslant (2a+1)\}|$. (iii) Calculate $\frac{1}{p^r}\sum_x N_{a,r}(x)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, I think so.